# Best way to insert data that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have the following the tables

**Temp user table**

*The content comes from an API*

```
-------------------------------------
| UserId  |   Location |  Department |
-------------------------------------
| 1       |  Loc1      |  Dep1       |
| 2       |  Loc2      |  Dep40      |
| 3       |  Loc100    |  Dep30      |
-------------------------------------
```

The goal here is to insert these data, however they belong to 3 different tables :

**User Table**

```
---------------------------------------
| UserId | LocationID |  DepartmentID |
---------------------------------------
| 1      |  1         |  1         |
| 2      |  2         |  2        |
--------------------------------------
```

**Department**

```
---------------------------------
| DepId |       DepName         |
---------------------------------
| 1      |  Dep1         
| 2      |  Dep40     
 ....
| 30 (new)|  Dep40 --> New value
----------------------------------
```

**Locations**

```
---------------------------------
| LocId |       LocName         |
---------------------------------
| 1      |  Loc1         
| 2      |  Loc240     
 ....
| 10 (new)|  Loc100 --> New value
----------------------------------
```

Based on this temp_user table, I should be able to add a new user and insert the missing department and locations to have something like this 
Considering for example:

- 30 is the id for Dep40
- 10 is the id for Loc100

My user table should looks like this

```
---------------------------------------
| UserId | LocationID |  DepartmentID |
---------------------------------------
| 1      |  1         |  Dep1         |
| 2      |  2         |  Dep40        |
| 3      |  10        |  30           |
--------------------------------------
```

**Question**

What is the best way to proceed this insertion? Can I do it with some triggers or should I create a stored procedure? What is the correct algorithm so?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Sorry, postgresql currently

Comment: Data comes from an API and it is stored like this in a temporary table

Comment: The best way to do it is to let someone else do it...

Comment: its a mistake, indeed i store the DepartmentID in users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the department name and the location name are unique, you can do something like this:

```
-- insert missing locations
insert into location (loc_name)
select location 
from temp_users
on conflict (loc_name) do nothing;

-- insert missing departments
insert into department (dep_name)
select department
from temp_users
on conflict (dep_name) do nothing;

-- insert new users
insert into users (id, location_id, department_id)
select tu.user_id, l.id, d.id
from temp_users tu
  join location l on l.loc_name = tu.location
  join department d on d.dep_name = tu.department
on conflict (id) do nothing; -- ignore existing users with the same ID
```

The above assumes that all `id` columns are defined as a primary key, that the ids for `location` and `department` are generated using a sequence (e.g. by defining them as `serial`) and that there are unique constraints defined on `location.loc_name` and `department.dep_name`.

Live example: http://rextester.com/SND63582

Comment: Well I didn't know about the "conflict (..) do nothing" statement, thanks a lot !